# Why is the database not detected when I run BLAST on Nextflow?

Tags: nextflow, blast

I keep getting the error that the database isn't detected when I run BLAST on Nextflow.

I used the following code and I cannot run the second process (extractTopHits) because I keep getting an error that says "No such variable: db"

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2
params.query = "/home/galaxy/Vivian/16s.fasta"
params.db = "/home/galaxy/Vivian/blastdb"

process blastSearch {
  input:
    path query
    path db
  output:
    path "top_hits.txt"

    """
    /home/galaxy/Vivian/ncbi-blast-2.13.0+/bin/blastn -db $db/16S_ribosomal_RNA -query $query -outfmt 6>    cat blast_result | head -n 10 | cut -f 2 > top_hits.txt
    """
}

process extractTopHits {
  input:
    path "top_hits.txt"
  output:
    path "sequences.txt"

    """
    /home/galaxy/Vivian/ncbi-blast-2.13.0+/bin/blastdbcmd -db $db -entry_batch  top_hits.txt > sequence>    """
}

workflow {
    def query_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.query)
    blastSearch(query_ch, params.db) | extractTopHits | view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example in the docs unfortunately is not correct and will not work as intended. The problem is that the `extractTopHits` input declaration does not specify a database directory so that it can be staged into the process working directory. You might prefer instead the following approach:

```
params.query = "/home/galaxy/Vivian/*.fasta"
params.db = "/home/galaxy/Vivian/blastdb/16S_ribosomal_RNA"

db_name = file(params.db).name
db_path = file(params.db).parent
```

```
process blastSearch {
  
    conda 'blast=2.14.0'

    input:
    path query
    path db
  
    output:
    path "blast_result.txt", emit: blast_result
    path "top_hits.txt", emit: top_hits

    """
    blastn \\
        -db "${db}/${db_name}" \\
        -query "${query}" \\
        -outfmt 6 \\
        > blast_result.txt

    cat blast_result.txt \\
        | head -n 10 \\
        | cut -f 2 \\
        > top_hits.txt
    """
}
```

```
process extractTopHits {

    conda 'blast=2.14.0'
    
    input:
    path top_hits
    path db
    
    output:
    path "sequences.txt"
    
    """
    blastdbcmd \\
        -db "${db}/${db_name}" \\
        -entry_batch "${top_hits}" \\
        > sequences.txt
    """
}
```

```
workflow {
    
    query_ch = Channel.fromPath( params.query )

    blastSearch( query_ch, db_path ) 
    extractTopHits( blastSearch.out.top_hits, db_path )

    extractTopHits.out.view()
}
```

Note that the above uses the [`conda`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#conda) directive so that we can avoid specifying absolute paths to the executables. Enabling  [Conda](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/conda.html) is as easy as adding the following to your `nextflow.config`:

```
conda {

    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not working since there is a an error (error exit status 1) on running the blastSearch

Comment: @Terra Sorry looks like I had some trailing whitespace in the BLAST commands. It is tested and working now, thanks!